# COLLATE MSSQL/PHP/FORM

Tags: php, sql-server, collate

I wanna to insert data to MSSQL by this:

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
$tsql = "INSERT INTO table (name, name2) VALUES('$name_demo','$name2_demo')";
```

My form looks like this:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST" id="sky-form2" class="sky-form">

      <fieldset>
        <div class="row">
          <section class="col col-6">
            <label class="label">NAME</label>
            <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append icon-user"></i>
              <input type="text" name="name_demo" required id="name_demo">
            </label>
          </section>
            <section class="col col-6">
            <label class="label">NAME2</label>
            <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append icon-user"></i>
              <input type="text" name="name2_demo" required id="name2_demo">
            </label>
          </section>
        </div>

      </fieldset>
      <footer>
           <button type="submit" value="submit" class="button">SEND</button>

      </footer>

      <div class="message"> <i class="icon-ok"></i><BR>
        <p>SENT!</p>

      </div>
    </form>
```

Everything works fine except that some letters like ąćęó into the database looks like Ä…Ä‡Ä™Ăł

For example such word like: LONDĄĆĘ in the database looks like: LONDÄ„Ä†Ä

Any idea? I was trying to play with collate in the database - nothing helps.

Comment: What does your database look like? Possibly you have wrong column types?

Comment: DataType is NVARCHAR(100)

Comment: Try using prepared statement? `sqlsrv_query($conn, "INSERT INTO table (name, name2) VALUES(?, ?)", [$name_demo, $name2_demo]);`

Comment: OK DONE: I've added to $connectionInfo "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8"

$connectionInfo = array("UID" => $usr, "PWD" => $pwd, "Database" => $db, "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");

WORKS NOW GOOD :)

Comment: Good to hear. You should still be using prepared statements anyway!